# Java adding objects to a child thread's message queue

Tags: java, multithreading, instance, message-queue

I have 2 threads, which communicate via a message queue.

If i do the following:

```
Messenger mess = new Messenger(); //Create an object of type Messenger
....
controller.enqueue(mess); //Adds it's reference to a message queue from another thread
....
mess = new Messenger(); //Create another object of type Messenger
....
controller.enqueue(mess); //Adds it's reference AS WELL to the message queue of another thread
```

My QUESTION here is:
Will this work? Will the message queue from controller have 2 objects in it? (in fact 2 references to the 2 objects)? Or will there be only one, the second one? Does the second object creation override the first one somehow?

Comment: It all depends on what `controller.enqueue()` does. Read its javadoc. Given its name, I would guess that enqueue adds the argument to a queue. And "adding" doesn't mean "replacing the last element". But I can only guess.

Comment: in fact controller is a Runnable and enqueue is my own method from a message queue class i created. So enqueue puts the objects it gets into an ArrayList

Comment: ArrayList.add() does add its argument to the list. Read its javadoc.

Comment: So you're asking us about the behaviour of a class *you* wrote, and whose code you haven't shown us?

Comment: Don't take it bad, but multi-thread programming is very very hard, and all kinds of subtleties must be understood to do it correctly. If you don't know how an ArrayList works and how objects and references work, you're not ready to program with multiple threads.

Comment: Why all the hate people? If you got nothing productive to say, then just don't say anything. And you could have asked nicely for the queue implementation. That's why this website exists, to clarify stuff like this.

Comment: If you want to use a work queue with a thread, I would use an ExecutorService.  This is thread safe, tested, built in and gives you both a queue and a pool of threads (can be just one)

Comment: Ok, i will check it out.

Comment: Sorry if my comment came across as hateful. But seriously, there is simply no way anyone could answer the question you asked in the form in which you asked it. Do you see that? So there's really no point asking it! Indeed, with your first comment on A.H.'s answer, you make it clear that this question is not about threads or queues at all, it's about the fundamental behaviour of variables in Java. That would have been a good question to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `enqueue` method receives two different references to two different objects. If the method does what its name and the name of the class promises, then the queue will indeed have two objects enqueued.

Comment: So at first i point to my object (Messenger) from mess. Then i add it to a message queue. Now i have two variables pointing to the same object(mess var and queueu)? I override the mess variable, with a new Messenger object (= new Messenger()). So now i have my queue pointing to my first Messenger object, and mess pointing to the second?

Comment: @AndreiBogdan If you mental instruction pointer is in the third '....' line: yes you are correct.

Comment: mess is a reference to a Message, not an object.  When you pass `mess` you are only passing the object you reference, i.e. not the same object each time, as you are changing the reference.  This is basic Java, nothing to do with how messaging or multi-threading works in particular.

Comment: No really sure what you are referring to by "mental instruction pointer" but that's ok :) I think i got it. Thank you both.

Comment: Yes, I think so. It's best to consider that 'mess' is invalid after its value is pushed onto the queue.  The thread above that is calling 'controller.enqueue' has effectively lost ownership of the Messenger. In fact, if you do try to reference it again after the enqueue, you might find that a consumer thread has dequeued it, processed it, nilled its own reference variable, its memory has been GC'd and reallocated to some other object. So, as soon as you enqueue, create another one - there should be no line of dots between the first enqueue() and the second new().